# While loop printing

Tags: java

How come my while loop continues to print "Please enter stock length(mm): "

code:

```
while (true) {
            // input stocks
            System.out.print("Please enter stock length(mm): ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int stockLength = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Please enter quantities of this stock length: ");
            int stockQuantity = sc.nextInt();
            Stocks stockObj = new Stocks(stockLength,stockQuantity);
            stockList.add(stockObj);
            System.out.print("Are you done? (y/n): ");
            String done = sc.nextLine();
            if (done == "y" || done == "yes") {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
Please enter stock length(mm): 4
Please enter quantities of this stock length: 4
Are you done? (y/n): Please enter stock length(mm):
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of sc.nextLine(), use `sc.next()`

```
String done = sc.next();
if (done.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || done.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
     System.out.println("breaking out of loop " + "Value of done: " + done)
     break;
}
```

Comment: the problem is still persistent =/

Comment: @Liondancer See(above) if it enters the if block and also check the value of done.

Comment: hmm, it doesnt enter the block

Comment: check the value of "done" before it enters the loop.

Comment: nothing but whitespace even when i enter `"y"` or `"yes"`

Comment: Once you fix your scanner and try the above, your program should work fine.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the my scanner usage? The edits you made didnt fix the issue =[ same problem is occuring